# Question on positive semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Suppose we have symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, where

$$A \succ 0, \qquad B \succeq 0, \qquad A - B \succeq 0$$

Here, $A \succeq B$ means that $x^\top Ax \geq x^\top Bx$ for all $x$.

1. Do we have $A^2\succeq B^2$?
2. If $S$ is positive definite, do we have $A S A \succeq B S B$?

It seems right, but I do not know how to prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

No, for a counterexample consider
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then $A-B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \geq 0$ but $A^2 - B^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is not PSD.

**Question 2**

No, take $S$ to be the identity matrix then $S$ is positive definite but by part $1$ the inequality cannot hold.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample!

Comment: Some keywords you may be looking for are "operator monotone functions". A function $f$ is operator monotone increasing if whenever $A \geq B$ we have $f(A) \geq f(B)$. Here we see that $x^2$ is not operator monotone but functions like $x^{1/2}$ and $\log x$ are.

Comment: Thanks for providing the information. Actually, my question is if $A$ and $S$ are PSD, do we have $A^{-1}SA^{-1}\geq (PAP)^- S (PAP)^-$, where $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix, and $(PAP)^-$ is the pesudo-inverse of PAP.

Comment: @beginner No that doesn't work, I tried a random example and it failed.